# How to better understand nested loops?

Tags: c++, loops, for-loop, nested, nested-loops

My problem is that I don't understand nested loops well enough to answer this problem. I'm supposed to right-align a stack that I've made on a left alignment using nested for loops, but I can't quite figure out the conditions on the two inner ones.

Correct answer:

```
Height = 8
.......#
......##
.....###
....####
...#####
..######
.#######
########
```

My answer:

```
Height = 8
.......#
.......#......#
.......#......#.....#
.......#......#.....#....#
.......#......#.....#....#...#
.......#......#.....#....#...#..#
.......#......#.....#....#...#..#.#
.......#......#.....#....#...#..#.##
```

I've played around with it, took it seriously and nothing. I did (k = 7, k > j, k--), (k = 0, k < n-1, k++), k < j+7, I drew tables and i know that the height is pretty much the same as the value of the spaces but inverted on each line. I also know that the value of the hashes and the spaces should be equal to the height input by user.

It's supposed to take in a value from user, but I've worked on it on a separate file with the value n being the height to simplify and work on it without the rest of the program.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int n = 8;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
            for(int k = 7; k > j; k--) {
                printf(".");
            }
            printf("#");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: So close. Try moving the `k` loop to outside the `j` loop.

Comment: You have your final loop too deep. Bring it out a step. You are almost there.

Comment: If it makes you feel better, I think your answer looks cooler

Comment: If you have completed your assignment, please consider posting it as an answer to your own question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's actually pretty simple. Write a table with each line and how many spaces and `'#'` you need to print:

```
n == 8

| output   | line | num_spaces | num_signs |
| -------- | ---- | ---------- | --------- |
| .......# | 1    | 7          | 1         |
| ......## | 2    | 6          | 2         |
| .....### | 3    | 5          | 3         |
| ....#### | 4    | 4          | 4         |
| ...##### | 5    | 3          | 5         |
| ..###### | 6    | 2          | 6         |
| .####### | 7    | 1          | 7         |
| ######## | 8    | 0          | 8         |
```

For `line` you can start from `0` or from `1` or from `n` and go backwards. Pick something that is the easiest. You will see that starting from `1` is the simplest in your example.

Now for each `line` we need to determine how many `num_spaces` and `num_signs` we print. They should depend on `line` and on `n`.

For `num_spaces` it's `n - line` and for `num_signs` it's `line`

So the code should look like this:

```
// for each line
for (int line = 1; line <= n; ++line)
{
    // print n - line spaces

    // print line # characters

    // print \n
}
```

With loops the code will look like this:

```
// for each line
for (int line = 1; line <= n; ++line)
{
    // print n - line spaces
    for (int i = 0; i < n -line; ++i)
        std::cout << ' ';

    // print line # characters
    for (int i = 0; i < line; ++i)
        std::cout << '#';

    std::cout << '\n';
}

std::cout.flush();
```

But that's actually not recommended. You can get rid of those inner loops. One good and easy way is to use strings:

```
// for each line
for (int line = 1; line <= n; ++line)
{
    // print n - line spaces
    std::cout << std::string(n - line, ' ');

    // print line # characters
    std::cout << std::string(line, '#');

    std::cout << '\n';
}

std::cout.flush();
```

And you can go even one step further:

```
// for each line
for (int line = 1; line <= n; ++line)
{
    // print n - line spaces and line # characters
    std::cout << std::string(n - line, ' ') << std::string(line, '#') << '\n';
}

std::cout.flush();
```